# Is it possible to have same Url pattern to access 2 method on Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm new to codeigniter,  i have a problem
Is it possible to have same Url pattern to access 2 different methods on Controller?
the difference is the method to access those methods is either GET or POST just like Spring MVC handles it

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAdd(Model model)

@RequestMapping(value = "/persons/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@ModelAttribute("personAttribute") Person person)
```

what i want is, when i access the url like this www.bla.com/controller/AddFunction (this is GET) the method that will be triggered is "add1" method which is will load view form and then i have form that has an "action" to controller/AddFunction, at this time because it is POST it will trigger "add2" method

thanks beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not required to pass the name of the REST method in the function call. The controller itself can handle input from a GET, POST, or both.

Example:

```
class Persons extends Controller{
  function add(){
    //$p will contain post data.
    $p = $this->input->post();
    //$g will contain get data.
    $g = $this->input->get();
    //$b will contain get or post data, depending on which is submitted.
    $b = $this->input->get_post();
  }
}
```

For further explanation see CodeIgniter's Documentation on [The Input Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Persons extends Controller{
  function add(){
    $postArray = $this->input->post();
    $getArray = $this->input->get();

    //if something was POSTed
    if($postArray){
        //do something with post array
        return; //early return
    }

    //if we need to GET
    if($getArray){
        //do something with get array
        return; //early return
    }

    //do something down here if there were no data passed, like a default view
    //get() and post() return false if you have no parameters sent

  }
}
```

Comment: what i want is, when i access the url like this www.bla.com/controller/AddFunction (this is GET) the method that will be triggered is "add1" method which is will load view form </br></br> and then i have form that has an "action" to controller/AddFunction, at this time because it is POST it will trigger "add2" method